# How to verify that a substitute received no calls at all?

Tags: nsubstitute

Using NSubstitute.
For some tests I want to assert that a Substitute has received *no calls whatsoever*. I could use `DidNotReceiveWithAnyArgs()` for every method in the interface, but that is tedious and not as robust (if a new method is added to the interface, a developer could easily overlook adding that to the test).

I'm looking for something *functionally* similar to Moq's `VerifyNoOtherCalls()` being called without any other Verify checks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The extension method `ReceivedCalls()`, which returns all calls that were received by the substitute, can be used to test that *no* calls were received.

For example (using FluentAssertions):

```cs
mySubstitute.ReceivedCalls().Should().BeEmpty();
```

Or using MSTest assertions:

```cs
Assert.IsFalse(mySubstitute.ReceivedCalls().Any());
```